# CakePHP (v1.1) - How do I retrieve a list of the models?

Tags: php, cakephp, model

Does anyone know if there's a simple way to retrieve the list of models in cakePHP v1.1? For example, if the app has models Student, Teacher, and Grade, I'm looking for a way to get an array of these models. Any suggestions? Thank you much.

Comment: You know never thought of that, see if you can check the source for [loadModel][1] which might help.


  [1]: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/845/loadModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best way to do this is to simply check which files exist in the models directory and check if they contain a class. I've decided that this is the best method based on the fact that this is essentially what the loadModel() function does itself. The code for the loadModel() function can be found [here](http://api11.cakephp.org/basics_8php-source.html#l00206). The program I ended up not needing to get the list of all models, but hopefully this answer can steer people in the right direction if anyone does need such a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the controller:

```
// Teachercontroller for example
$this->Teacher->hasMany;
```

this gives back all the related Models.
Same with *belongsTo* etc.

Comment: This gives all models related to Teacher, but I'm looking for something that will retrieve all models in the entire app. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: oh ok sorry, got your question wrong then. how about reading the files from the Model folder. This way you will get all Models with their correct Name.